# Unable to receive message for reused socket on iOS10

Tags: ios, sockets

Here is a weird thing, I create two sockets and bind them to the exactly same address(`INADDR_ANY`) and port.

When `SO_REUSEADDR` is set to both socket, the second bind will fail with error `EADDRINUSE`.

When `SO_REUSEPORT` is set to both socket, all bind call will succeed, but only the first socket could receive data, the socket which bind later will never receive any data.

I'm currently working on iOS 10, and I believe it works differently on Android.
Anyone has seen the same problem? Is this an iOS intended behavior? How could I receive data for the second socket without release the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple demo I can confirm that this is intended behavior of iOS(and similar BSD based systems) , and Linux/Android will behave oppositely.